# How to run large Javascript code in Selenium, php?

Tags: php, javascript, selenium

I am using Selenium version 1, with PHP. I need to execute a large Javascript code snippet. When I use the `runScript()` function, it gives me this error:

> Request URI Too Large

How can I handle this? Or is it possible to include it as an external js file but run it as well at once? I have tried using the `addScript()` function, that contains my js code, but it did not work. I have also tried to include my all code in a function like this:

```
function executeMyCode() {
  // all my code here
}
```

And then include it with `addScript()`, and then use `runScript()` like this: `$this->selenium->runScript('executeMyCode()')`.

But it did not work either.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason for such large js execution through Selenium? It seems like something you should try and avoid instead of pursue.

Comment: I need to change the structure of the page, which I can not do by selenium.